# Custom response from htaccess for a web-request

Tags: apache, .htaccess

What here I am trying to achieve is to return proper response from the htaccess file instead of redirecting to some other file to save few file oparations. For example, for a URL request, localhost/a.js, I only want to return something like

```
function square(val)
{
  return (val*val);
}
```

And only for this, I don't want another directory traverse and read.

Comment: This is not what a configuration file is for. It should control request flow, not generate content itself.

Comment: @arkascha, well it does in case of ErrorDocument so, couldn't it do the same for a URL request situation?

Comment: I never claimed it can't. I only pointed out that this is not what it is for.

Comment: @arkascha, Yes, I know what it is for and yes it is not a optimal use of the htaccess. But in my certain situation, it seems to be a good idea. However the question remains unanswered, that is "How to do that?"

Comment: Also you appear to have a wrong understanding of what such dynamic configuration file actually does: "instead of redirecting to some other file" This is not a redirection at all. If you are really concerned about performance, then simply stop dynamic configuration files, _those_ cause a huge performance impact. Use the _real_ http server's configuration instead.

Comment: @arkascha, sorry, but I know what it does. Atleast, almost I know what it does. About having real urls, that is not practically possible for any website. so yes, the performace impact will be there. Question is can I improve it? The only way of khowing this is by omplementing it if possible.

Comment: No idea what you are trying to say by that. What does "real URLs" mean here? I said nothing about URLs... What I suggested is that if you are concerned about performance then stop using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess") and start using the real http server configuration file. Those offer the same options at a _much_ better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this is not possible to add code to the apache configuration.

There is the option of configuring Apache to run [CGI scripts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html) . You can use any language (compiled or interpreted script) to create a CGI program, but the output must be valid HTML. These are typically run from a cgi-bin directory within the web space.

Alternatively you could use  [Apache SSI](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/ssi.html) (Server Side Includes) SSI and exec to a script, though this poses a security risk that you would need to consider. SSI is really only for adding some very basic dynamic content to a page.

You could just use a server side scripting language (e.g. PHP) which is designed to process web content efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. though, as for 404 or other errors, we have option either to return a file name or directly return HTML content, I thought may be I can do the same. Did I miss something?

Comment: Responding to a defined set of error status codes is a thing that is frequently needed, by almost any website. Your very special requirement is exactly that - terribly special, and not a normal use case by any stretch of the imagination. No one has implemented anything like that therefor yet.

Comment: @misorude, Not implemented then no problem and this is what I thought at the first place but just wanted to confirm with the community if it is doable or not.